# Create a video from images with transition animation

Tags: ios

I already created the video with images. But I need to place the transition  Animation in between the effect frame changing from one to another.

Comment: You can do your animation and can capture video of the screen. Ref https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: have you find any solution? I am in stuck with the same problem :( @rptwsthi

Comment: @pigeon_39 Pavan will be right person to ask.

Comment: ohh sorry...thanks for your correction
have you find any solution? I am in stuck with the same problem :( @Pavan Kumar Gadipudi